# Blocked by CORS Policy on Local Machine, but not on remote test server

Tags: vuejs3, fetch-api

```
  mounted() {
    const headers = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 
            "Authorization":"whm test:code",
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',        
            'Content-Length':'0',        
        },
    };
    fetch("https://example.com/json-api/uapi_cpanel?api.version=1&cpanel.function=add_pop&cpanel.module=Email", headers)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => (this.postId = data.id));
    }
}
```

I am using the above code with my domain instead of example.com.

I do not have access to the origin API, I just have access via token.

Weirdly, this won't work, but will work fine on https://reqbin.com/.

To add to the weird-ness, if I use the same, but use cURL and PHP, works.

The PHP/ cURL version works completely fine, no issue exactly the same headers, body..

To add to the confusion, both PHP and this VueJS is running on localmachine.

```
Access to fetch has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I don't understand why it will work on Regbin and if I code the same request in PHP cURL it will work, but not via fetch in VueJS..